# How do I make a navbar pop up when I click on an icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm a beginner trying to learn react and watched this tutorial on making a navbar. For a smaller screen size I followed it to make a navbar that pops up on the side when I press the menu icon. Ive made the navbar that pops up on the side and to hide it, I used translatex(-500px). Now I dont know how to get it to pop up when I press the icon, should I use some code inside css or use an onclick function what would be more efficient?

````
      ```
              function NavBar() {
        return(
             <div>
                <nav>
                    <div className="logo">React Nav</div>
                    <ul id="bc" className="nav-links">
                        <li><a>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a>Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <i onClick="burger()" className="fas fa-bars burger"></i>
                </nav>
            </div>

            )
    }
      ```
````

this is the navbar code

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav .burger {
    display: block;
  }

  nav .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
  }
```

this is the css for the side navbar

```
import React from "react";


const burger = () => {
    document.getElementbyId("bc").className = "bclick";
}

export default burger;
```

I tried making this function and passing it as onclick in the i tag and then I had another class called bclick which was translateX(500px) but that didnt work

Comment: If you can shar your all code would be useful and I see that you are doing document.getElementbyId("bc").className = "bclick"; which has no point to do in react

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of React. You will want to look into "state", or if you are using React 16.8+ the `useState` hook. Learn more about hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

---

Your code could be something like this:

```js
function NavBar() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div className="logo">React Nav</div>
        <ul className={isOpen ? "nav-links is-open" : "nav-links"}>
          ...
        </ul>
        <i onClick="() => setOpen(!isOpen)" className="fas fa-bars burger"></i>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
```

Add this to your css, so the navigation bar is visible again, when `open`

```css
  nav .nav-links.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

---

Final remark: translateX(500px) is just moving your navigation bar into the opposite direction, but you probably want it show show in its actual position - thus resetting the transformation with `translateX(0)`.